# Can we declare two or more schema in hibernate config file?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using `Hibernate4` in my project with `Spring3` and `JSF2` , i have a question in my mind in my hibernate config file i am using

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">whse</prop>
```

Can we add more `schema` in config file?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: This is what my question can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `

> @Table(catalog="")

` to specify database to which they belong to and then also can make relation across database.

original answer by jigar see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877734/hibernate-using-two-different-database-schemas-in-the-same-application) for reference